# Spring MVC how to modify existing _id index for mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, spring-data

By default, it looks like Mongo adds an index named `_id_` for the `_id` field of the document.

In spring, I'm trying to make that index unique but the following code doesn't work : (it doesn't do anything)  I know the syntax is correct since if I change that code to create an index on a different field, it works.

```
@Document
@CompoundIndexes(value=@CompoundIndex(name="_id_", def="{'_id':1}", unique=true))  
public class Message {

@Id
private String messageId;
```

My question is, how can I modify/update make the _id index unique using Spring ?

Comment: Has nothing to do with spring, but it's about MongoDB. You just cannot modify  the primary key because it is required. Are you actually trying to just create a compound value on the `_id` field instead?

Comment: The default index on `_id` is already unique.

Comment: No the default index on ID is NOT unique, and I can verify this since mongo allows a document with the same ID to be saved again.  Well, actually, it saves it again but overwrites the previous document.  I would expect it to fail with duplicate key exception.

Comment: @Marc That doesn't show the index isn't unique.  That's a different issue, related to how you're trying to create the duplicate doc, with the driver assuming you mean to update the existing one instead.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, you are correct.  As a test, I tried inserting a new document with an existing ID and got the duplicate key error, so obviously it is unique. That means you're also correct that my code (or spring) is trying to update the doc instead of creating a new one.  I'll update with a solution when I have one (code wise) thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, @JohnnyHK's answer is correct, the default _id index in MongoDB is unique, so the problem lies in spring.

I've logged this question instead :

[spring mongorepository is updating or upserting instead of inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032981/spring-mongorepository-is-updating-or-upserting-instead-of-inserting)