# Spring MongoRepository is updating or upserting instead of inserting

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I'm using a :

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
```

I start with an empty DB and create an object with `_id = 1234` for example, and set some other String field to `hello` for example, and then do:

```
repository.save(object);
```

All is well, it saves the document in MondoDB.

I create a NEW object, set the same `_id = 1234` but set the other String field to `world` and then to another save :

```
repository.save(newObject);
```

Results : the save works but updates the original object.

Expected results: This should fail with a `DuplicateKeyException` as `_id` is unique and I am using 2 separate objects when doing each save.

Defect in spring or am I doing something wrong ???

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Save**, by definition, is supposed to update an object in the upsert style, update if present and insert if not.
Read the `save` operation documentation on the MongoDb [website](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/)

The **insert** operation in mongodb has the behavior you expect, but from the MongoRepository documentation it appears that insert is delegated to save so it won't make any difference. But you can give that a try and see if it works for you. Otherwise you can just do a get before to check if the object exists, since it is an index lookup it will be fast.

**Edit**: Check your repository version, *insert* was introduced in [version 1.7](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html#insert-S-).

Comment: The problem is that `_id` seems to behave different than any other field.  For example, if I have a field called `name` in the mongo document, and create a UNIQUE index on that field, doing the steps mentioned in my question will result in an expected `DuplicateKeyException` being thrown.  Furthermore, for the spring mongorepository API, there is no `insert` API, only `save`.  I have a feeling this is a bug in spring.

Comment: There is an insert method: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html#insert-S-

Comment: The index validation is different, the optimization in save is that it can directly update the object if it is found, this is by design.

Comment: Ah, I'm using an older version which doesn't have the `insert`  API.  Thanks for pointing that out, I'll upgrade Spring and test `insert` and report back with my results later.  Thanks alot.

Comment: awesome, I updated my Spring data and spring data mongo versions which now supports `insert` and bingo, I get a duplicate key exception ! thanks alot !

Comment: Saying that an insert is the same as a read and then save is NOT accurate.  Inserts are helpful because they are atomic on single documents.  If you read, then a write happens from a different thread, then you write, you can break a lot of patterns that use insert.

Answer (score 17):

the  application shall update only when you have @Id annotation for one of the field, after long difficulty had found this

```
@Document(collection="bus")
public class Bus {

//  @Indexed(unique=true, direction=IndexDirection.DESCENDING, dropDups=true)
    @Id
    private String busTitle; 
    private int totalNoOfSeats;
    private int noOfSeatsAvailable; 
    private String busType; 
}
```

but somehow I could not use 
@Indexed(unique=true, direction=IndexDirection.DESCENDING, dropDups=true)

Comment: don't mixup `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` and `javax.persistence.Id` like me, the first one should be used !